# Bash script: how to replace text from user input

Tags: linux, bash

I need to make an interactive bash script where the user will input a word, for example 'xyz' and it will replace a word in a text file.

For example, I have a script called example.sh. When i run it, it should ask:

```
What is your name?: 
and the user will input 'xyz'.
```

The script should take that input and replace 'username' inside a text file called userlist.txt to 'xyz'

to be more clear, I need user input to run

`sed -i -e s/username/userinput/g userlist.txt`

Comment: Do you have any code that you've tried so far?  Can you add it to your post?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`read` builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-read) to read user input, and you can then use [`sed(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) to do the text replacement:

```
if read -p "What is your name? " name; then
  sed -i~ -e "s/username/${name}/g" userlist.txt
else
  # Error
fi
```

Comment: I can't make this work, the username just gets replaced by ${name}, on Arch Linux

Comment: EDIT: The name has "/" in it. like /dev/sda. So I get error "unknown option to 'd', unknown option to 's'"

Comment: @user156238: The problem is, you aren't passing `$name` to `sed` like an argument: you are dynamically constructing a command using the value of `$name`, and so any characters in the variable that have special meaning to `sed` are treated as such. You'll need to preprocess the value of `$name` before using it with `sed` to quote such special characters: a non-trivial task.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "What is your name?"
read name
sed -i -e s/username/"$name"/g userlist.txt
```

Comment: I can't make this work, the username just gets replaced by "$name", on Arch Linux

Comment: @user156238 Weird, worked for me on Linux Slackware. And Adam Rosenfields answer worked too - I tested them both.